# jQuery multiple .closest not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, closest

I am trying to get second li's attr data-uid value on-click event.

jQuery code:

```
$(document).on('click', 'ul li ul li ul li div.k-bot', function(){
    alert($(this).closest('li.k-item').attr('data-uid')); //its giving first one's data-uid
    alert($(this).closest('li.k-item').closest('li.k-item').attr('data-uid')); //its also giving first one's data-uid
});
```

Html Code:

```
<ul class="k-group" role="group">
    <li role="treeitem" class="k-item" data-uid="104321c5-b0bd-4225-8804-38467ac111bf" data-expanded="true" aria-expanded="true">
        <div class="k-top">
            AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
        </div>
        <ul class="k-group" style="display: block; overflow: visible; height: auto;" role="group">
            <li role="treeitem" class="k-item k-last" data-uid="05ca21d3-cc54-40c2-b3cb-6dde8299a1d7" aria-selected="true">
                <div class="k-bot">
                    BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
                </div>
                <ul class="k-group" style="display:none" role="group">
                    <li role="treeitem" class="k-item k-last" data-uid="ffb02246-030b-4264-87c7-68030e25d6e4">
                        <div class="k-bot">
                            CCCCCCCCCCCCCC
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Why its happening like this?

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/749Lxd3f/)

Comment: Have you tried .parent( ?

Comment: or .siblings() ? please add a fiddle

Comment: `ul li ul li ul li div.k-bot` < - overkill! use more *unique* classes or something, that's a horrible way to select an element.

Comment: Any chance that event handler is triggered for *both* `.k-bot` elements? It's really hard to say due to the selector. Which is very bad by the way -- instead of `ul li ul li` etc, give an id or class to some "root" element and take it from there.

Comment: @Novocaine Yeah i know, actually that is kendo-ui tree view. its generating dynamically. I am just passing a javascript Object to it.

Comment: @Jon i want click event only for third li div.k-bot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) for .closest:

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the
>   selector **by testing the element itself** and traversing up through its
>   ancestors in the DOM tree

The result from the first `closest` is itself `li.k-item` therefore the subsequent call matches it. Use this instead:

```
$(this).closest('li.k-item').parent().closest('li.k-item').attr('data-uid')
```

[<kbd>jsFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/et97uqe7/)

Comment: Perfect it works, Thanks. Can you clarify my doubt? See in this  `$(this).closest('li.k-item')` it will give the first parent `li.k-item`. If i am using another closest on it, It should give me Second parent one.

Are you saying that this is same as. we call multiple function on once element in inline. like `$(this).html('').show().addClass('XYZ')`

Answer (score 0):

Little easier to read (uses delegation so you don't need such a huge selector list):

```
$(document).on('click', '#myid', '.k-bot', function(e){
    console.log($(e.target).parent().attr('data-uid')); 
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mj1xt8e2/